# How to get C function name in code diff using "P4 diff" command?

Tags: diff, perforce

Is there any equivalent option of  in perforce (P4) command-line to get function name in code diff?
I need to have function name corresponding to each code diff segment in generated diff file.
This will help me navigate to function call from code-diff using CTAGS.

Comment: The diff output is line oriented; that is, it describes which line(s) are different between the two versions being diff'd. Given those line numbers, you can locate that position in the file: for example, use the "go to line number N" feature of your text editor. Then you will see what function you are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this excerpt from `p4 help diff`:

> If the environment variable $P4DIFF is set,  the specified diff
>   program is launched in place of the default Perforce client diff.

It happens that if `P4DIFF` includes spaces, `p4` treats it as an executable name with arguments, so you can do:

`export P4DIFF="diff --show-c-function"`

(or an equivalent for whatever console shell you're using) then when you run `p4 diff`, you should see function names for C-based code.

Comment: Thanks jamesdlin! I was asking about P4, your suggestion was helpful, it solved my problem. Thanks.,